# Error for ftplib.cwd: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, ftp, iso-8859-1, ftplib

There are many posts about 'latin-1' codec , however those answers can't solve my problem, maybe it's my question, I am just a rookie to learn Python, somewhat. When I used `cwd(dirname)` to change directory of FTP site, the unicodeerror occurred. Note that `dirname` included Chinese characters, obviously, those characters caused this error. I made some encoding and decoding according to the suggestions in the past posts, but it didn't work.
Could someone give me some advice how to repair this error and make `cwd` work?

Some codes:

```
file = 'myhongze.jpg'
dirname = './项目成员资料/zgcao/test-python/'
site = '***.***.***.***'
user = ('zhigang',getpass('Input Pwd:'))    
ftp = FTP(site)
ftp.login(*user)            
ftp.cwd(dirname)# throw exception
```

---

Some tests:

```
u'./项目成员资料/zgcao/test-python/'.encode('utf-8')
```

Output:

```
b'./\xe9\xa1\xb9\xe7\x9b\xae\xe6\x88\x90\xe5\x91\x98\xe8\xb5\x84\xe6\x96\x99/zgcao/test-python/'
```

---

```
u'./项目成员资料/zgcao/test-python/'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
```

Output:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 10: character maps to <undefined>
```

---

```
u'./项目成员资料/zgcao/test-python/'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
```

Output:

```
'./é¡¹ç\x9b®æ\x88\x90å\x91\x98èµ\x84æ\x96\x99/zgcao/test-python/'
Using the result of decode('latin-1'), the cwd can't still work.
```

---

It is noted that `项目成员资料` is showed as `ÏîÄ¿×é³ÉÔ±Ë½ÈË¿Õ¼ä` when I used `retrlines('LIST')`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to edit ftplib source code. Just set `ftp.encoding` property in your code:

```
ftp.encoding = "UTF-8"
ftp.cwd(dirname)
```

A similar question, about FTP output, rather then input:
[List files with UTF-8 characters in the name in Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53091871/850848)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by editing `ftplib.py`. On my machine, it is under `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib`.

You just need to replace `encoding = "latin-1"` with `encoding = "utf-8"`

Comment: Thanks for Stephen Hoo's answer，After changed the ftplib.py encoding type, I've downloaded the file successfull. But the encoding type should be fits your ftp server, not just `utf-8`, in my case which is Windows NT with encoding type GBK, so the `encoding = "gbk" `

Comment: Reposted from a comment by Andrew zhong: *After changing the ftplib.py encoding type, I downloaded the file successfully, but the encoding type should be what fits your ftp server, not just utf-8, in my case which is Windows NT with encoding type GBK, so the encoding = "gbk".*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do not change the source code of the package, just reload the ftp object and modify the encoding type, for example:

```py
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
ftp.encoding = 'utf-8' # Here you can modify the encoding property of the object
```