# List files with UTF-8 characters in the name in Python ftplib

Tags: python, utf-8, ftp, decode, ftplib

I need to mirror files from an FTP server to a local machine, but some files/directories have special characters on it, e.g:

```
print(ftp.nlst())
>>{'Mariana', 'Marina', 'MartÃ\xadn', 'MatÃ\xadas'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the filenames are in UTF-8 encoding, in Python 3, this should do:

```
ftp.encoding = "UTF-8"
print(ftp.nlst())
```